# How can I write this more efficiently without repeating myself?

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery and having a blast, but I feel my code is very repetitive and there must be a smarter way to do it and I'm keen to learn how. The idea of the code is to show/hide a div with information when clicking a button. I got 9 buttons that show a piece of information.

I have 9 buttons with an 'item-content-div' for each. The code works but I am copy/pasting the code 9 times and changing the button and ítem-#-content' for each. Is there a method/way to write this better?

```
    $(".button1").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-1-content").addClass("active");
    })

    $(".button2").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-2-content").addClass("active");
    })

  $(".button3").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-3-content").addClass("active");
    })

   $(".button4").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-4-content").addClass("active");
    })

   $(".button5").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-5-content").addClass("active");
    })

   $(".button6").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-6-content").addClass("active");
    })

   $(".button7").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-7-content").addClass("active");
    })

   $(".button8").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-8-content").addClass("active");
    })

   $(".button9").click(function() {
      $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
      $(".item-9-content").addClass("active");
    })
```

Here is the relative DOM, including the data-idx method which works great.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-content item-1-content active">
      <h2>Item 1 active</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item-content item-2-content">
      <h2>Item 2 active</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="1"></div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="2"></div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="3"></div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="4"></div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="5"></div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="6"></div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="7"></div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="8"></div>
  <div class="itembttn" data-idx="9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant DOM (for one or two of those buttons).

Comment: Added, sorry for not including that when posting.

Comment: There's no element with a `buttonX` class o.O

Comment: Please post the HTML as it was when you asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the version using index (starts at 0)

```js
$(".itembttn").on("click", function() {
  $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
  const idx = $(this).index();
  $(`.item-${idx+1}-content`).addClass("active");
})
```

```css
.active  {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-content item-1-content active">
      <h2>Item 1 active</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item-content item-2-content">
      <h2>Item 2 active</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="itembttn">1</div>
    <div class="itembttn">2</div>
    <div class="itembttn">3</div>
    <div class="itembttn">4</div>
    <div class="itembttn">5</div>
    <div class="itembttn">6</div>
    <div class="itembttn">7</div>
    <div class="itembttn">8</div>
    <div class="itembttn">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or maybe use DOM traversal - **after** OP has specified the actual setup...

Comment: This works great and is much cleaner indeed! Is there a way to avoid adding the data-idx in the HTML but instead let jQuery check how many buttons there are? Or am I overthinking it now?

Comment: @JaPPa I think, you can use .index() function.
  
$(".itembttn").on("click", function() {
    $(".item-content").removeClass("active");
    $('.item-' + ($(this).index()) + '-content').addClass("active");
  })

Comment: See updated code

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan! So if I understand it correctly it is the same method but instead of declaring the idx in the HTML you use the index function to count the number of 'itembttn' and output the corresponding number into the item-#-content div. Which does the same but this method is dynamic as it can be 1.000 and still index them?

Comment: Yes that is correct